# Isotropy and Homogeneity of the internal Schwarzschild Metric

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, symmetry, coordinate-systems

I've been working on a paper involving the internal Schwarzschild metric and something I've been told multiple times is that the internal metric is not isotropic.  I understand that the external metric is not isotropic, but I was (I believe) able to show that the internal metric is in fact isotropic by examining the geometry in Kruskal coordinates, yet I'm still just told that it's anisotropic without any explanation.  The angular term of the internal metric has time as a radius, and that term seems to be the basis for the insistence of anisotropy, but I also demonstrate that the angular term describes the precession of a gyroscope relative to the past boundary (event horizon) of the metric (i.e. Thomas Precession) and therefore does not result in an anisotropy of the geometry.

I'm asking if anyone can help me identify what the logical flaws are in the analysis below because I have so far been unable to get any specific feedback on it, so I am hoping someone here may be able to help me understand why the arguments below do not in fact prove isotropy of the internal metric.  I've summarized the arguments from the paper below:

The the external and internal forms of metric can be expressed as (coordinates in the external metric are primed to distinguish them from the internal metric coordinates):
\begin{equation}\label{extschwmetric}\tag{1}
 d\tau'^2=\frac{r'-r_s}{r'}dt'^2-\frac{r'}{r'-r_s}dr'^2-r'^2d\Omega'^2%
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{schwmetric}\tag{2}
 d\tau^2=-\frac{u-r}{r}dt^2+\frac{r}{u-r}dr^2-r^2d\Omega^2%
\end{equation}
Equation \ref{extschwmetric} is the external metric with $t'$ being the timelike coordinate and $r'$ being the spacelike coordinate.  The Schwarzschild radius of the metric is given by $r_s=2GM$ in units with $c=1$.  We use the prime notation for the coordinates here to distinguish the external coordinates from the internal coordinates.

Equation \ref{schwmetric} is the internal metric with $t$ being the spacelike coordinate and $r$ being the timelike coordinate.  This metric is currently believed to describe the interior of a Black Hole.  But consider the case of a spherically-symmetric vacuum surrounded by a spherically-symmetrically distributed infinite amount of mass.  This would be a spacetime surrounded by a shell with an infinite Schwarzschild radius (because the mass of the shell is infinite).  Since this is a spherically symmetric vacuum, it must be described by the Schwarzschild metric.

The figure below shows the Kruskal-Szekeres coordinate chart.
[image: Kruskal]

On this chart, the external metric is in quadrant I and the internal metric is in quadrant II (note that in quadrant II, $t$ is the spacelike coordinate, and $r$ is the timelike coordinate).

Now we must show that the space in the internal metric is isotropic and homogeneous.  The equation for a 2D hyperboloid surface embedded in three dimensions is given by:
\begin{equation}\label{hyperqun}\tag{3}
 \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}=\pm1
\end{equation}
For our purposes, we will be considering the special case where $a=b=c$, which gives the one and two sheeted hyperboloids of revolution.  Next, we note the following relationship with regards to the Kruskal coordinates:
\begin{equation}\label{kruskalrelate}\tag{4}
 X^2-T^2=\left(\frac{r}{u}-1\right)e^{\frac{r}{u}}
\end{equation}
Equation $\ref{kruskalrelate}$ is only for one dimension of space, but we know that the metric is spherically symmetric and can therefore extend Equation \ref{kruskalrelate} to 2 spatial dimensions by simply adding a Y coordinate to get an equation that matches the form of Equation \ref{hyperqun} where $a^2=b^2=c^2=\left(\frac{r}{u}-1\right)e^{\frac{r}{u}}\equiv\rho^2$:
\begin{equation}\label{kruskalrelate2}\tag{5}
 X^2+Y^2-T^2=\rho^2
\end{equation}
Equation \ref{kruskalrelate2} describes 2D hyperboloid surfaces for a given $r$ where the external metric has positive $\rho^2$ and the internal metric has negative $\rho^2$.  This means that the external metric describes a 1-sheet hyberboloid while the internal metric describes a 2-sheeted hyperboloid.

We will for now focus on regions I and II from Figure 1, where region I captures the external metric and region II captures the internal metric.  If we choose some constant value of $r=r_0$ in each region and plot Equation \ref{kruskalrelate2} for each region, we get the surfaces shown below:

[image]

In the internal case where we have two separate sheets, we will only focus on the top sheet for now.  In the external metric, the sheet represents an equatorial circle of space around the central body at all times.  This circle is on a plane with a normal at the center and pointed vertically in the above figure.  If we then consider circles on all planes whose normals are at different angles relative to the normal of the plane we are currently visualizing, we get a 2D spherical surface representing the space surrounding the central body at constant $r$.

Light cones in the figure above are oriented vertically and light travels on 45 degree lines.  If we consider the right side of the above figure, representing the external metric, choose any point on the surface and project a past and future light cone out of that point (this will just be a vertical cone centered at that point).  We see that the external metric is anisotropic and inhomogeneous because the surface is asymmetric relative to the surface left and right as well as into and out of the page.  But the light cone is symmetric vertically relative to the surface.  We can see this because we are allowed to circularly and/or hyperbolically rotate any point to a point at the throat of the surface and the space will remain unchanged.  This is because the metric is spherically symmetric (representing circular rotations) and static (representing hyperbolic rotations).  It becomes clear that the cone is vertically symmetric relative to the surface at the throat since both the cone and surface are vertically symmetric in a plane parallel to the throat.  So any point we choose to start with can be moved to the throat of the surface and we see that the cone is vertically symmetric relative to the surface when we move a point there.

Now consider the top sheet on the left side of the above figure representing the internal metric.  Again choose any point on the surface and project a past and future light cone vertically from that point.  Just like in the case of the external metric, we can move that point anywhere on the surface to the apex of the surface by hyperbolically and/or circularly rotating the point there (and the space will remain unchanged).  When the point is rotated to the apex, we see then that the light cone is symmetric relative to the surface left and right and into and out of the page.  This symmetry means the internal metric is isotropic and homogeneous.  The cone is not vertically symmetric relative to the surface, however, and that reflects the fact that the internal metric is not static.

The above arguments tell us something important about the Schwarzschild metric.  When the metric is derived from Einstein's field equations, it is usually done from the perspective of the external metric.  In the derivation, we assume spherical symmetry and a static spacetime.  It is notable that in spite of the static assumption, we still get an internal metric that is non-static.  This is because the static assumption for the external metric is actually an implicit assumption of hyperbolic symmetry.  Therefore, we can more correctly state that the Schwarzschild metric is the vacuum solution to Einstein's field equations that is both spherically and hyperbolically symmetric.  This hyperbolic symmetry manifests itself as a static metric when the time coordinate is hyperbolic (the external metric) and an isotropic and homogeneous metric when the space coordinate is hyperbolic (the internal metric).

We can further extend this model to three spatial dimensions by adding a $Z^2$ term, but given the spherical symmetry we can define $R^2\equiv X^2+Y^2+Z^2$ and change Equation \ref{kruskalrelate} to
\begin{equation}\label{kruskalrelate3}\tag{6}
 R^2-T^2=\rho^2
\end{equation}
In this formulation, we get homogeneous and isotropic spherical surfaces for each $t$ (as opposed to circles in the 2D case of Equation 5.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion between the isotropy (i.e. spherical symmetry) of a spacetime - which is a coordinate-independent notion - and the isotropy of a *coordinate chart*, which obviously is not.  The defining characteristic of an isotropic coordinate chart is that the line element takes the form $\mathrm ds^2 = -A(r) \mathrm dt^2 + B(r)\big(\mathrm dr^2 + r^2 \mathrm d\Omega^2\big)$, with $t$ the timelike coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to analyze symmetries is through the use of Killing vector fields. These are proper tensors, so they do not depend on your choice of coordinates. Regardless of which coordinates you use, the Schwarzschild spacetime has [four Killing vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_coordinates#Killing_vector_fields) fields. In standard Schwarzschild coordinates they are:

$$\partial_t$$$$\partial_\phi$$$$ \sin\phi \, \partial_\theta + \cot\theta \, \cos\phi\, \partial_\phi $$$$ \cos\phi \, \partial_\theta - \cot\theta \, \sin\phi\, \partial_\phi $$

The latter three indicate that the spacetime is isotropic, and this holds regardless of your coordinates. The spacetime is not homogenous, so the isotropy is a global isotropy and not an isotropy about every point. So it doesn't make sense to talk about it being isotropic in one region vs another. It is the spacetime as a whole that is isotropic.

Comment: Thanks.  What is it that indicates that the spacetime is not homogenous?

Comment: (I mean spatially homogenous, i.e. a surface of fixed r in the internal metric)

Comment: There are no spacelike translational Killing vectors. The only spacelike Killing vectors are the rotational ones.

Comment: But the dt Killing vector is a spacelike vector in the internal metric since t is spacelike for the internal metric, no?

Comment: That is a good point. It is still not homogenous because homogeneity would require three spacelike translational Killing vectors, not just one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand in what way the internal geometry is not homogenous in this case given the geometry of the 2-sheeted hyperboloid discussed in the post (as discussed, the t coordinate is hyperbolic and so the dt Killing vector would point in every direction as can be seen in the 2-sheeted hyperboloid diagram), but I'll need to go learn more about Killing vectors in this context.  Thanks.

Comment: Spatial homogeneity requires 3 translational Killing vectors, one for each spatial direction. It has 0 outside the horizon and 1 inside the horizon. So it is not spatially homogenous. The spacetime that is both isotropic and homogenous is the FLRW spacetime used in cosmology

Comment: Added a full response to this below.

Comment: I don’t know what to tell you. $3\ne 1$

Comment: @Dale How are you distinguishing rotational from translational Killing vector fields?

Comment: @TimRias that is a good point. I was calling ∂t translational simply because the integral curves of ∂t are open and go out to infinity. But they are also non-geodesic and their magnitude is a function of r, so maybe calling ∂t “translational” is inappropriate

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add an argument based on @Dale's response regarding Killing vectors above and the relationship to homogeneity of the internal metric.  Recall that for the internal mettric, the $t$ coordinate is spacelike and therefore the $\partial_t$ Killing vector represents a symmetry in $t$.  I'm arguing that at fixed time $r$ in the internal metric, represented by the top sheet of the 2-sheeted hyperboloid in the original post, the space is homogenous.  That 2-sheeted hyperboloid surface represents 2D of space, but the argument applies to the full 3D because of the spherical symmetry.  I plotted the $\partial_t$ Killing vectors on the surface in the figure below.  The vectors are tangent to the surface in the direction of any hyperbola on the surface.
[image]

At the apex of the surface ($t=0$ in the Kruskal coordinate chart in the original post and the bottom point on the surface in the above image), you can draw a $\partial_t$ Killing vector in every direction (i.e, move all the Killing vectors shown in the image above to the bottom point on the surface and you will have vectors originating from that point pointing in every direction on a plane tangent to that point).  And since you can hyperbolically rotate any point on the surface to the apex without changing the geometry, this means that at every point on the surface there are $\partial_t$ Killing vectors pointing in every direction and therefore the surface is homogeneous.  This is also true in 3D because of the spherical symmetry, but 4 dimensions would be required to visualize that.

Comment: The key mistake here is “the argument applies to the full 3D because of the spherical symmetry”. Spherical symmetry implies isotropy, not homogeneity. So arguing that you have homogeneity because of spherical symmetry is a complete non sequitur.

Comment: But to go to full 3d, the circles shown on the surface (contours of consstant $t$) just become spheres, so the result is the same in 3D

Comment: An important point here is that $t$ is the radius of the circles shown on the surface (more easily seen on the bottom surface), so $\partial_t$ is a radial direction in space.  So the $\partial_t$ and $\partial_{\Phi}$ Killing vectors are both spacelike and cover the surface in 2D such that that surface is homogenous.

Comment: ChrisLaforet said “cover the surface in 2D such that that surface is homogenous”. First, $2\ne 3$ so this is still not spatial homogeneity.  Second, $\phi$ is a spherical coordinate. $\partial_\phi$ is non uniform in size, has vanishing points, and its integral curves are closed. So what you are calling “homogenous” is not what everyone else means by the word even for a 2D surface. Anyway, I have given my feedback. You may choose to learn or ignore, I am done arguing

Comment: I appreciate the input